# ZF2 Form Collection with fieldset stays in old state if validation fails

Tags: php, forms, validation, collections, zend-framework2

I have a form object with the following collection element:

```
$languageSkills = new Collection('languageSkills');
$languageSkills->allowAdd();
$languageSkills->allowRemove();
$languageSkills->setLabel('LANGUAGES_SKILLS_QUESTION');
$languageSkills->setCount(0);
$languageSkills->setShouldCreateTemplate(true);
/* @var $fieldset LanguageSkillFieldset */
$fieldset = new LanguageSkillFieldset();
$fieldset->setMasterDataService($masterDataService);
$fieldset->init();
$languageSkills->setTargetElement($fieldset);
$this->add($languageSkills);
```

The fieldset itself contains a hidden field and a select box.
now if i change a value in a fieldset or i add/remove a fieldset dynamically (with js), send the form and something is not valid, then the collection appears in its old/previous state (without any changes). All other elements have the correct values.

What am I doing wrong?

Here the controller part:

```
$form = $this->getSkillForm();
$prg = $this->prg($this->url()->fromRoute('langroute/freelancer/profile/skills/save', array(), array(), true), true);
// check PRG plugin for redirect to send
if ($prg instanceof Response) {
    return $prg;
} elseif ($prg !== false) {
    $flashMessenger = $this->flashMessenger();
    // if none is selected, there is no entry in array
    if (empty($prg['driversLicenses'])) {
        $prg['driversLicenses'] = array();
    }
    if (empty($prg['languageSkills'])) {
        $prg['languageSkills'] = array();
    }
    $form->setData($prg);
    $form->bind($this->getFreelancer());
    try {
        $this->getFreelancerService()->updateFreelancer($form->getValidatedObject());
        return new JsonModel(array('success' => 1));
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        $flashMessenger->addErrorMessage($ex->getMessage());
    }
}
$model = $this->getSkillsEditViewModel();
$model->setVariable('form', $form);
return $model;
```

-> inside the getValidatedObject() method (of my class AbstractForm extends Form):

```
if(!$this->isValid()) {
    throw new ValidationException($message, $this->getInputFilter());
}
return $this->getObject();
```

Comment: Please post the code for the appropriate action in the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a while i found the fix for this issue. Be careful that you validate your form **before** you bind an object! Bind it **after** validation, before the further processing like persisting or so. That was the point, thanks anyway...